# Levenshtein distance on diacritic characters

Tags: php, levenshtein-distance

In PHP I am calculating Levenshtein distance using function levenshtein(). For simple characters it works as expected, but for diacritic characters like in example

```
echo levenshtein('à', 'a');
```

it returns "2". In this case only one replacement has to be done, so I expect it to return "1".

Am I missing something?

Comment: you probably need a multibyte compatible levenshtein implementation, [try this one](https://gist.github.com/santhoshtr/1710925) (first one on google)

Comment: It is explained nicely [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php#113702).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default PHP `levenshtein()`, like many PHP functions, is not multibyte aware. So, when processing strings with Unicode characters, it handles each byte separately and changes two bytes.

There is no multibyte version (i.e. `mb_levenshtein()`) so you have two options:

1) Re-implement the function yourself, using `mb_` functions. [Possible example code from a Gist](https://gist.github.com/santhoshtr/1710925):

```
<?php
function levenshtein_php($str1, $str2){
    $length1 = mb_strlen( $str1, 'UTF-8');
    $length2 = mb_strlen( $str2, 'UTF-8');
    if( $length1 < $length2) return levenshtein_php($str2, $str1);
    if( $length1 == 0 ) return $length2;
    if( $str1 === $str2) return 0;
    $prevRow = range( 0, $length2);
    $currentRow = array();
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $length1; $i++ ) {
        $currentRow=array();
        $currentRow[0] = $i + 1;
        $c1 = mb_substr( $str1, $i, 1, 'UTF-8') ;
        for ( $j = 0; $j < $length2; $j++ ) {
            $c2 = mb_substr( $str2, $j, 1, 'UTF-8' );
            $insertions = $prevRow[$j+1] + 1;
            $deletions = $currentRow[$j] + 1;
            $substitutions = $prevRow[$j] + (($c1 != $c2)?1:0);
            $currentRow[] = min($insertions, $deletions, $substitutions);
        }
        $prevRow = $currentRow;
    }
    return $prevRow[$length2];
}
```

2) [Convert your string's Unicode characters to ASCII](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php#113702). If you are specifically wanting to calculate Levenshtein differences from diacritic characters to non-diacritics, though, this is probably not what you want.

Comment: I consider 1 option a better suited for my case, as I will have to calculate Levenshtein distance for other unicode characters as well. But I made little corrections to it: 1. `if( $length1 == 0 ) return $length2;` changed to `if( $length2 == 0 ) return $length1;` (because at that point $length1 will always be bigger or equal to $length2). 2. moved `if( $str1 === $str2) return 0;` to start of the function, as it will give result instantly.

Comment: Wouldn't `if( $length1 == 0 ) return $length2;` be best to replace with `if( $length1 == 0 ) return 0;`, since at that point if `$length1` is 0, than both strings are empty. And in fact if you have moved `if( $str1 === $str2) return 0;` to the start, that case was already handled, so after all with your 2nd change the 1st is indifferent, the whole `if( $length1 == 0 ) return 0;` can be thrown out.

Answer (score 4):

I thought it may be useful to have [this comment from the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php#113702) posted as an answer to this question, so here it is:-

The levenshtein function processes each byte of the input string individually. Then for multibyte encodings, such as UTF-8, it may give misleading results.

Example with a french accented word :
- levenshtein('notre', 'votre') = 1
- levenshtein('notre', 'nôtre') = 2 (huh ?!)

You can easily find a multibyte compliant PHP implementation of the levenshtein function but it will be of course much slower than the C implementation.

Another option is to convert the strings to a single-byte (lossless) encoding so that they can feed the fast core levenshtein function.

Here is the conversion function I used with a search engine storing UTF-8 strings, and a quick benchmark. I hope it will help.

```
<?php
// Convert an UTF-8 encoded string to a single-byte string suitable for
// functions such as levenshtein.
// 
// The function simply uses (and updates) a tailored dynamic encoding
// (in/out map parameter) where non-ascii characters are remapped to
// the range [128-255] in order of appearance.
//
// Thus it supports up to 128 different multibyte code points max over
// the whole set of strings sharing this encoding.
//
function utf8_to_extended_ascii($str, &$map)
{
    // find all multibyte characters (cf. utf-8 encoding specs)
    $matches = array();
    if (!preg_match_all('/[\xC0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]+/', $str, $matches))
        return $str; // plain ascii string

    // update the encoding map with the characters not already met
    foreach ($matches[0] as $mbc)
        if (!isset($map[$mbc]))
            $map[$mbc] = chr(128 + count($map));

    // finally remap non-ascii characters
    return strtr($str, $map);
}

// Didactic example showing the usage of the previous conversion function but,
// for better performance, in a real application with a single input string
// matched against many strings from a database, you will probably want to
// pre-encode the input only once.
//
function levenshtein_utf8($s1, $s2)
{
    $charMap = array();
    $s1 = utf8_to_extended_ascii($s1, $charMap);
    $s2 = utf8_to_extended_ascii($s2, $charMap);

    return levenshtein($s1, $s2);
}
?>
```

Results (for about 6000 calls)
- reference time core C function (single-byte) : 30 ms
- utf8 to ext-ascii conversion + core function : 90 ms
- full php implementation : 3000 ms