# How does Oracle DB compute edit distance and similarity with non-ASCII characters?

Tags: sql, oracle, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance

I've recently been working with Oracle DB, and when evaluating their matching functions (in this case, `EDIT_DISTANCE` and `EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY`, which - I think - implement unnormalized and normalized Levenshtein distance) against standard implementations, I stumbled over some curious behaviour.

Normally, I would expect a normalization equal to:

```
1 - edit_distance / len(longer_string)
```

However, this doesn't perfectly match Oracle's results, nor do the unnormalized edit distance values themselves always match expections.

More specifically, my testing suggests that both functions seems to handle special characters strangely. I've tested German and French special characters, and both seem to be handled different from ASCII characters.

For example, here are results given by Oracle DB (I'm scaling Oracle normalization from [0, 100] down to [0, 1]), and what I would expect based on the standard Levenshtein algorithm and the formula above:

| String A | String B | Expected edit distance | Oracle edit distance | Expected normalization | Oracle normalization |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stack | stock | 1 | 1 | `1 - 1/5 = 0.8` | 0.8 |
| müll | mall | 1 | 2 | `1 - 3/4 = 0.75` | 0.6 |
| déja-vu | deja-vu | 1 | 2 | `1 - 1/7 = 0.857` | 0.750 |
| château | château! | 1 | 1 | `1 - 1/8 = 0.875` | 0.89 |

The SQL I'm using to arrive at these results is as follows (replace 'a' and 'b', obviously):

```
SELECT UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE('a', 'b') FROM dual;
SELECT UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE_SIMILARITY('a', 'b') FROM dual;
```

All of the Oracle results are plausible if you count special characters as two characters. This is, at first, somewhat sensible for German umlauts, for which "ae", "oe", and "ue" are common substitutions, but I'm not aware of similarly common substitutions for e.g. French (then again, my French is quite rusty).

Even more strangely, "Müller" compared with "Mller", "Muller" and "Mueller" returns an edit distance of 2 for all three cases, so "ü" isn't simply converted to "ue". This, therefore, definitely does not seem correct.

It seems strange to me that Oracle is treating non-ASCII characters like this. Is there any precedent or "scientific basis" for this behaviour? For me, it seems pretty random, and in fact more like a bug.

Disclaimer: the entire behaviour could also be due to the version of DBVisualizer (the SQL client) or Oracle DB I'm working with. I unfortunately don't have an easy way to eliminate this variable due to installation restrictions in the environment I'm working in.

Comment: side note: the post creation wizard really shouldn't forcefully stop me from posting a question just because of a non-code-formatted maths like `1 - 1/5 = 0.8` inside a table, or at least should highlight better what the actual problem is. But oh well ...

Answer (score 2):

Look at the byte values of the strings:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (A, B) AS
SELECT 'stack',   'stock'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'müll',    'mall'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'müll',    'mall'     FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'déja-vu', 'deja-vu'  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'château', 'château!' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```
SELECT a,
       b,
       DUMP(a),
       DUMP(b),
       UTL_MATCH.EDIT_DISTANCE(a, b) AS edist
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

| A | B | DUMP(A) | DUMP(B) | EDIST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| stack | stock | Typ=1 Len=5: 115,116,97,99,107 | Typ=1 Len=5: 115,116,111,99,107 | 1 |
| müll | mall | Typ=1 Len=5: 109,195,188,108,108 | Typ=1 Len=4: 109,97,108,108 | 2 |
| müll | mall | Typ=1 Len=6: 109,117,204,136,108,108 | Typ=1 Len=4: 109,97,108,108 | 3 |
| déja-vu | deja-vu | Typ=1 Len=8: 100,195,169,106,97,45,118,117 | Typ=1 Len=7: 100,101,106,97,45,118,117 | 2 |
| château | château! | Typ=1 Len=8: 99,104,195,162,116,101,97,117 | Typ=1 Len=9: 99,104,195,162,116,101,97,117,33 | 1 |

The `müll` and `müll` values look identical but the first is created with a single character `LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS` and the second is created with two characters `LATIN SMALL LETTER U` and then the diacritic `COMBINING DIAERESIS`.

The edit distance is calculating the edit distance between the bytes (or ASCII values) rather than the edit distance between multi-byte characters (or, even more complicated, the edit distance between multi-byte characters modified by combining diacritics).

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZAlfLoPT)

Comment: Great analysis! However, the difference between the two "müll" variants is not really the core issue; the first (shorter) variant already has an edit distance of 2, where I would expect 1. That more complicated variants reach a difference of 3 instead of 1 is just the cherry on top. I can see where this behaviour is coming from thanks to your analysis, but I still think this behaviour is extremely unintuitive, and I would consider it a bug in Oracle's implementation tbh.

Comment: @PixelMaster At best, I would say this is a documentation problem as the [documentation states](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/UTL_MATCH.html) that `EDIT_DISTANCE` "calculates the number of insertions, deletions or substitutions required to transform string-1 into string-2." without stating what it means by "insertions, deletions or substitutions". You have assumed it means characters whereas the implementation appears to be using bytes. Just because your assumption does not match the actual behaviour does not mean it is a bug.

Comment: That's very nitpicky. Sure, entirely out of context, "edit distance" can be used to compare just about anything. However, the documentation STRONGLY suggests this is used for characters, not for bytes or something else. Here are some quotes from the documentation: "[the UTL_MATCH package] is typically used to match names", and "Edit Distance, also known as Levenshtein Distance [...] is a measure of similarity between two strings". A string in programming is practically always a character string, if no further restrictions are given. Plus, all examples in the documentation compare char strings.

Comment: And while yes, you could argue that the documentation is wrong (maybe some guy wrote the code, and another person the docs, who knows), I don't think that's sensible. I'm pretty sure that 95% of people would expect this function to compare the characters, not the bytes, because the former use case is (in my opinion) what 95% of people actually want to accomplish when they calculate edit distance (and also what Levenshtein is designed for). Rather, I would think this behaviour is indeed an oversight, since the problem simply doesn't occur in standard English, which doesn't have such characters.

Comment: @PixelMaster You are generating a lot of assumptions on what the behaviour "should" be. From my point of view, an edit distance function should be fast and algorithmically simple. When you add edge cases of "is it a multi-byte character" (or worse, a 1-byte character then a multi-byte combining diacritic character) then it gets more complicated and slower. Then you come to culture specific things; should `ß` and `ss` have an edit distance of 0? There is a trade off between efficiency and complexity and Levenshtein Distance tends to err towards efficiency rather than supporting unicode strings.

Comment: This is also standard behaviour in other languages - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/26271656/1509264